# How does phpmyadmin implement "search" feature?

Tags: sql, database, phpmyadmin

In `phpMyAdmin`, there is a `search in database` feature by which I can input a word and find it in any table(s).

How to implement it by SQL statement? I know the `LIKE` operation, but it's syntax is:

```
WHERE column_name LIKE pattern
```

How to search in all columns? Any how to specify it's a exact keyword or regular express?

Comment: I suggest looking at its source code...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM your_table_name WHERE your_column_name LIKE 'search_box_text';
```

Where search_box_text is what you enter in the search. It will also say in the result page what kind of query it made. The same query with regular expressions is:

```
SELECT * FROM your_table_name WHERE your_column_name REGEXP 'search_box_text';
```

Remember that the wildcard in mysql is %. Eg. "LIKE '%partial_search_text%'

If you want to search in multiple columns, you can check which columns are in table with:

```
DESCRIBE TABLE your_table_name;
```

Or if you already know your columns:

```
SELECT * FROM your_table_name 
WHERE your_column_1 LIKE '%search%' 
AND your_column_2 LIKE '%search%'
AND your_column_3 LIKE '%search%';
```

Comment: But it needs a `your_column_name`. phpMyAdmin doesn't.